# How to solve this WebStorm error related to git

Tags: git, ubuntu, webstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Lately I bumped from a 2022 version to WebStorm 2023.2

After the upgrade the git integration in WebStorm broke, bringing up following error on every action via the integrated Git GUI.

```
/bin/bash: line 1: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8): No such file or directory not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

The git commands are working well from terminal, the projects `.git` is fine. While I have no issue using the git commands instead in general, I really don't want to miss the GUI when it comes to resolving merge conflicts.

My project is in a WSL2 Ubuntu instance of a Windows 10 machine. This was working before the WebStorm upgrade.

I already tried to reach out to WebStorm support, but got no response.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing the autodetected git executable (`Settings > Version Control > Git`). Before it was using the git executable of the WSL2 instance, now WebStorm uses the git executable of the Windows Host.